# How to create a JSON list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have to form a JSON object like

```
var SelectedRows=   {
        "item1":{"id":"1","name":"jhon","phone":"6699"},
        "item2":{"id":"2","name":"Aron","phone":"7799"},
        "item2":{"id":"3","name":"Iyan","phone":"8899"},
        }
```

On check box click event, I need to add the grid row values to the JSON list. I am trying with this code:

```
var SelectedRows={};

$(this).delegate(":checkbox", "click", function() {        
    var j=0;
    var item=[];
    SelectedRows[item]={};        *//I guess this line creating problem*     
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td:visible").each(function(){            
        var key=headerRow[j]["i"];            
        if(j == 0)
        {              
        }
        else
        {   
            SelectedRows[item][key]=$(this).text(); 
        }
        j=++j; 
     });
```

After multiple checkbox click events happening,`SelectedRows` contains only last click event data.

How get all the checkboxes click events data?

Comment: This is a funny JSON object you're trying to create. Why not use an array instead of adding elements with dummy keys *item1*, *item2*, *item3* etc.? And why does each item consist of an array with just a single element?

Comment: `var item[];` is not valid Javascript, what are you trying to do with that?

Comment: @Barmar, It's typo error, i edited that.

Comment: Now you're using an undefined variable `item`.

Comment: @Codo, I am using these keys(id,name,phone) on server side, so i decide to create json object. above json object format might be wrong(dummy keys item1,item2, item 3 etc).I need JSON object like asp.net list.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an json array like this

```
var SelectedRows=   [
    item1:{id:"1",name:"jhon",phone:"6699"},
    item2:{id:"2",name:"Aron",phone:"7799"},
    item2:{id:"3",name:"Iyan",phone:"8899"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `var item[];` by `var item = 'item'+(j+1);` and result should like..

```
var SelectedRows=   {
    "item1":{"id":"1","name":"jhon","phone":"6699"},
    "item2":{"id":"2","name":"Aron","phone":"7799"},
    "item2":{"id":"3","name":"Iyan","phone":"8899"},
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I done like this. it is displaying exactly above format.

```
var SelectedRows=[];
var rowCount=1;
```

Used extra count variable to from item1, item2, item3 etc..

```
    $(this).delegate(":checkbox", "click", function() {
        var j=0;
        var item={};    
            $(this).closest("tr").find("td:visible").each(function(){
               var key=headerRow[j]["i"];
                   if(j == 0){ }
                   else {
                          item[key]=$(this).text();
                        }
               j=++j; 
            });
            SelectedRows["item"+rowCount]=item;
            rowCount=++rowCount;
  });
```